# How can I bind pressing a button and hitting an enter key in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to bind pressing a button and hitting an enter key.

I'm using Python 3.

Here's my code :

```
class MakeaButton(object):
    def sizedButton(self, root, x, y):
        f = Frame(self.root, width = 100, height = 35)
        f.pack_propagate(0)
        f.place(x = x, y = y)

        self.btn = Button(f, text = 'Button', command = self.destroy)
        self.btn.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)

    def background(self):
        def close_onclick():
            sys.exit()

        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry('1160x640')

        self.sizedButton(self.root, 530, 450)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def destroy(self):
        self.root.destroy()
```

I want to make my code to destroy the window both when I press the button and when I hit the entry key when the focus is on the button.

How can I make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `bind()`:

```
def sizedButton(self, root, x, y):
    f = Frame(self.root, width = 100, height = 35)
    f.pack_propagate(0)
    f.place(x = x, y = y)

    self.btn = Button(f, text = 'Button', command = self.destroy)
    self.btn.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)
    self.btn.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e, b: self.destroy()) # for click
    self.btn.bind("<Return>", lambda e, b: self.destroy()) # for return
```

Comment: Thanks. But there comes an error : 
TypeError: destryo() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given. When I press the button, the error comes out, but the window openes. But When I hit the enter key, the error comes out, and the window doesn't open.

Comment: @HoseongJeon: oh, right. change it to `lambda e, b: self.destroy()` because the callback sends two arguments

Comment: Thanks. It didn't correctly at first, and when I changed 'lambda e, b' to 'lambda e', it worked. Thank you very much